# Setting up SparkR in RStudio in Windows platform. JVM is not ready after 10 seconds

Tags: r, windows, apache-spark, rstudio, sparkr

I am trying to set up SparkR in Rstudio in Windows platform. I have installed Spark and from the command prompt I can execute the Sparkr.exe. But when I try to get the Spark Context in RStudio I get the following error:

> **Error in sparkR.init(master = "local") :    JVM is not ready after
>   10 seconds**

Here are the steps I followed in Rstudio. Please suggest where I am going wrong.

```
if (nchar(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME")) < 1) {
  Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "C:\\Spark\\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6")
}
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))
library(SparkR, lib.loc = "C:\\Spark\\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\\R\\lib")

library(SparkR)
library(rJava)
library(jsonlite)

sc=sparkR.init(master="local")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing you the procedure that I followed to integrate SparkR in RStudio. 
First I assume that you have already installed spark and environmental variable are also updated in Windows.

Procedure to get SparkR running in RStudio

1. Fisrt locate R folder under spark folder(like C:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6)
2. Under lib folder you will get SparkR folder, that have to zip it and give it a name SparkR.
3. Open RStudio ==> Click Tools ==> Install from Archive ==> Install

Once you are done with the above procedure just call `library(SparkR)`
You will be able to run SparkR.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I installed Spark and the environmental variables are setup. I can also load the SparkR library in RStusio. But I start facing problem when trying to get the Spark context using    sc=sparkR.init(master="local") . Error is "JVM is not ready after 10 seconds". FYI, I have also started the SparkR from the command prompt before executing this command.